# How to set path for typeface for a font file in android

Tags: android, typeface

I am using typeface class to set the font Monotype corsiva for an edittext

```
 EditText ed=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editexthead);
 String path="C:\\MTCORSVA.TTF";
 Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromFile(path);
 ed.setTypeface(tf);
```

The program force closes with an exception
Is there any other way to set the path..

And when i try to manually store a .TTF on sdcard it doesn't show up the file... any reason for that. 
I don't want to use assets folder to set the font ... anybody with the solution .. ??
Please HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you not want to store it in the assets folder? That's what it's for. Regardless, you can't reference your local hard drive for it.

(also, personal opinion, Monotype Corsiva is a horrible, horrible font)

EDIT: So I would add, you should be able to do it the way you're doing it, you just can't use your local hard drive. Just get a reference to your TypeFace as a `File`, depending on where you are saving them (e.g. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`) and use `Typeface.createFromFile(file)`.

Comment: thanks man for an early reply, basically its like am parsing a xml file which is placed on server, the file has a field named fontstyle="anyfont" for each editext,textview,button etc... so if i keep it in assests folder i'll have to do if else conditions which makes my work more tedious.... Anyways i think i'll have to do it like that only...    and yeah i too hate Monotype Corsiva font its just that while programming i copied a font without seeing its name only for testing purpose... thanks once again

Comment: No need to accept so quick if the answer doesn't help. :) But I've edited in something that I hope may help.

Answer (score 1):

Store the font file in the assets directory and get to it with this code:

```
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "MTCORSVA.TTF")
 view.setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: @Martyn- i tried it in that way but it limits me to use only assets folder ... Is no other option available ..????

Comment: Nope - that's what the assets folder is for!  Also you can't write to the assets folder during runtime - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399505/copy-file-to-assets-folder